# Font-awesome icons not appearing

Tags: font-awesome

I have an application running in 2 ubuntu servers, one local with virtual box and the other in amazon.

I configured both, so it's practically the same.

The same code display the font-awesome normally in the virtual server but not in the amazon server.

I checked if everything is loading, and it is!

In chrome it display as empty squares, and in safari it doesn't display at all.

I'v tried some .htaccess configurations I found googling but no lucky.

You can check in: `http://54.94.183.185/`

Comment: I don't see any empty squares.

Comment: How about using a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the traffic between your browser and the two servers in order to determine the difference?

Comment: Juhana - I just sent an update so the icons appear in the index.
Richard - Does finddler works on mac?

Comment: Your font mime type is wrong. It should be `application/font-woff` and yours is `application/xfont-woff`

Comment: I fixed through .htaccess but but still not working!